# Migrating from Angular 1.0.8 to 1.2.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration

I've tried to migrate to the latest production version of Angular, and it wasn't a pleasant experience.

I've followed the [migration document](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration), the only part of which I've seen relevant to me is the part about the underscore prefix \ private attributes.

Still the screen freezes with no error code, particularity at the watchers processing line 11381 at the non-minimized angular file, tried debugging, but no luck so far.

Also the templates break, and get concatenated to one another when changing routes, and the angular template syntax is displayed on the screen instead of the needed values, some repeaters are not working, and some AJAX requests are looping.

What course of action should I take?, where do I start?.

Answer (score 2):

Try their official documentation:

Migrating from 1.X to 1.2
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: I have referred to this document in the body of the question, it is general and not specific, as most of their documentation,
Thanks for your time.